# Devise 'translation missing' error with subclassed controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I've subclassed `Devise::RegistrationsController`.  The subclassed controller, in my case, is `AdminRegistrationsController`.

But, when I sign up a new admin, for example, the `flash` shows the message:

`translation missing: en.devise.admin_registrations.admin.signed_up`

I've verified an entry exists in `config/locales/devise.en.yml`.  Here's the snippet:

```
en:
  devise:
    registrations:
      signed_up: 'Welcome! You have signed up successfully.'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must do this :

```
en:
  devise:
    admin_registrations:
      admin:
        signed_up: 'Welcome! You have signed up successfully.'
```