# Devise : translation missing: fr.devise.failure.user.not_found_in_database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When I want to subscribe as a user with Devise. I have this following message: "translation missing: fr.devise.failure.user.not_found_in_database"

Please could you tell what could I do?

Thank you for your back

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620767/devise-translation-missing-error-with-subclassed-controller) to do something simmilar or try the devise i18n documentation [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n)

Comment: Thank you but what can I do to solve the problem do I create a new file or folder?

Comment: Concretely, download the correct `yml` file for your language from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n and place it inside `config/locales/` - you'll likely see `devise.en.yml` already in there.

Then, set your default locale in `config/application.rb` by modifying/adding:
`config.i18n.default_locale = :fr` (replace with language abbreviation from your yml)